# How to send a webhook from Visual Studio App Center to Google Hangouts

Tags: webhooks, google-hangouts

I'm trying to set up an incoming webhook to post to my Google Hangouts chat from Visual Studio App Center. However I am not able to do so with an error message from App Center.

Here is the sample JSON message from App Center:
{"app_name":"myFirstApp","branch":"master","build_status":"Succeeded","build_id":"33","build_link":"https://appcenter.ms/users/yuli1/apps/myFirstApp/build/branches/master/builds/33","build_reason":"manual","finish_time":"2018-06-14T23:59:05.2542221Z","icon_link":"https://dl0tgz6ee3upo.cloudfront.net/production/apps/icons/000/590/821/original/0c9130028703e417a6a0df02c6b587f0.png","notification_settings_link":"https://appcenter.ms/users/yuli1/apps/myFirstApp/settings/notifications","os":"iOS","start_time":"2018-06-14T23:57:03.4379381Z","source_version":"55820a357ba26831f2eeb3be9973a4ef20618b73","sent_at":"2018-06-14T23:59:08.4897604Z"}

What am I doing wrong here?
How can I get the webhook URL from Google Hangouts?

Thanks!
Amanda

Comment: To update, here is the webhook URL from Google Hangouts: https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAex-Uqaw/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=_B9jrbSHpaR6We3Zx0oZwkDgzJ1-IDtRLa5eraUtoDE%3D

Comment: Hi, are there any updates/solutions to this issue?

Comment: Hey Google team, do you have any updates?